# how to regex match exactly one id in url?

Tags: javascript, regex

How do i match the url below ?

I want my regex to return true if my url pattern is

```
/products/e2e-test-products-2022-08-17T18-30-49-882Z:7ebee29f-dde2-4446-b2b1-327c15fbbabb/items
```

and return false when the url is

```
/products/e2e-test-products-2022-08-17T18-30-49-882Z:7ebee29f-dde2-4446-b2b1-327c15fbbabb/cart/items
```

Comment: Your title is a bit confusing when reading the question. Are you trying to match any url with one "word" after the ID or specifically `THEID/items`?

Comment: The only difference I see is `/cart` in the second one. You want to exclude that?

Comment: I want regex to match when the url is /products/:id/items. but i want it to return false when it's /products/:id/carts/items. 

is this slightly better?

Comment: When regex is your only hammer, every problem looks like a thumb

Answer (score 1):

```js
const myRegex = /^\/products\/[^/]*\/items$/;
myRegex.test('/products/e2e-test-products-2022-08-17T18-30-49-882Z:7ebee29f-dde2-4446-b2b1-327c15fbbabb/items')
true

myRegex.test('/products/e2e-test-products-2022-08-17T18-30-49-882Z:7ebee29f-dde2-4446-b2b1-327c15fbbabb/cart/items')
false
```